# IONIC - can't access externalDataDirectory on $ionicView.enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to read a directory to check how many files exists
When I open the app I get this error

> ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'externalDataDirectory' of undefined

But when I go to another view, and came back, this works fine.
I try to call the same function on 
`$ionicPlatform.ready` and works, but this way is executable only once, I need to call every time I enter on this page.

Anyone had this error before?
I'm using ionic v1 and $cordovaFile extension
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with `$ionicPlatform.ready`:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // cordova file code
  });
});
```

Comment: I already tried, but this way it is executed just once, and a I need in every page load

Comment: as long as you call it inside `$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter')` (as shown in my example), it will be executed everytime the user enters the view

Comment: You are righ, but this way in the first execution i have the error